# How to display sheet(s) on dashboard using navigation?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm creating a dashboard on Tableau and I want to have a set of navigation buttons that correspond with the sheets I've created. When a button is clicked I want the corresponding sheet to be displayed on my dashboard instead of navigating to the sheet itself. I want all of the sheets to be displayed in the same place on my dashboard. For example, If button 1 is clicked I want sheet 1 to be displayed on my dashboard. If button 2 is clicked I want sheet 2 to be displayed on the dashboard in the same place. I'm new to Tableau and would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is using parameters.

As a first step you need to creat a parameter with a list of values matching the number of worksheet, like: Worksheet 1, Worksheet 2, etc...

Then you have to create N calculated fields in order to check if the "actual" worksheet is the one "selected in the parameter", using "ok" and "ko" as results for your filters, keeping just "ok".

The formula could be something like this (assuming you're doing the CF for the 1st worksheet, and the other ones differ just for the value):

```
if parameter = 'Worksheet 1' then 'ok' else 'ko' end
```

Doing so, all you're worksheets will present data just one at a time because all of them but the one matching the valus in parameter will be blank.

Then you can create your dashboard putting a vertical (horizontal as well if you like) container in it which will be the the "place" where you'll drag all your worksheets.

Be sure to NOT modify the spacing and height of them; just le tableau handle that for you, otherwise the trick won't work.

Once you're finished you will end up having a container with N worsheets in it, with just one of them dysplayed at once.

Once you'll become familiar with parametr actions, you will no longer need to have the parameter displayed on the dashboard (show parameter) because using a worksheet connected to the parameter values you will be able to decide the value of the parameter via click on your additional worksheet acting like a series of button (woeksheet 1, worksheet 2, etc...)